# jQuery HTML append causes UTF-8 national language chars issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, utf-8

I encountered problems appending html that returns from UTF-8 powered InnoDB MySQL database -- object actually, that is fulfilled with data and returned to be displayed by jQuery asynchronously. The website, and database are using UTF-8 only.

So when I post something, it goes to the database, inserted, object is fulfilled with data that I inserted and appropriate html returned to jQuery, which unfortunately for some of the reason, instead of national letters, displays things like: `u0142u00f3`, etc.

When I refresh the website, it backs to normal, and chars are displayed properly.

Ideas?

Before it goes to the DB class:

```
$strNoBreakSpace = mb_convert_encoding('&#x00A0;', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
$strNormalSpace = mb_convert_encoding('&#x0020;', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
$ntc = str_replace($strNoBreakSpace, $strNormalSpace, $content);
```

After got back from DB class:

```
$thread= str_replace(array(chr(10), chr(13)), '', $thread);
$thread_html = json_encode(array('status' => 1, 'success' => $thread_html));
array_push($results, $upd, $ins, $thread_html);
```

Before showing to jQuery:

```
    $list = array('success' => stripslashes($result[2]));
```

Is it stripslashes what ruins it? I needed to add this, and these mb_converts, else I had problem with json object within that html, having lots of slases /td, /tr\, \r\r, etc.

What jQuery sees is:

```
{"status":1,"success":"<tr>                    <td class="col-md-1">27.09.15</td>ttt        <td class="col-md-1 ws-nowrap"><a href="#"><span class="label label-info label-as-badge">Test</span></a></td>                    <td class="col-md-5"><a href id="id" name="id" href="#">u0142u00f3</a></td>                    <td class="col-md-5">u0142u00f3</td>                </tr>"}
```

Comment: You are stripping the slashes in someway, the data should be: `\u0142\u00f3` which is: `łó`

¿Can we see some code?

Comment: Hi Marcos, added some code to the above post. Thanks for support!

Comment: Can you add the content of $result[2] so I can give you a correct answer.

Comment: Added to the thread :)

Comment: Not exactly sure what's "ttt        " after td, it's not in my code..., there should be only first td with date, second with category (as badge), and third with content.

Comment: this is within the object class:  <td class="col-md-5">' . strip_tags($content) . '</td>

Comment: So seems like I'm using, strip_tags, then stripslashes

Comment: I meant the content of $result[2] in PHP before striping slashes, or the content of the MySQL table which has the HTML you are printing. So I can run some tests using the same string you have.

Comment: This is the exact string when I removed strip_tags, and stripslashes. String: {"status":1,"success":"<tr>                    <td class=\"col-md-1\">27.09.15<\/td>\t\t\t        <td class=\"col-md-1\"><a href=\"#\" style=\"text-decoration:none;\"><span class=\"label label-info label-as-badge\" style=\"font-weight:normal;\">Test<\/span><\/a><\/td>                    <td class=\"col-md-5\"><a id=\"id\" name=\"id\" href=\"page\/1\">\u0142\u00f3<\/a><\/td>                    <td class=\"col-md-5\">\u0142\u00f3<\/td>                <\/tr>"}

Comment: Im decoding that string perfectly. Can you give me the string before any formatting, before striplash, strip_tags, the raw MySQL table content, the string as soon as you perform the query. Thanks

Comment: Hmz, so maybe TinyMCE is messing things up, cause input is taken from tiny, but website is <meta charset="utf-8">. Database is InnoDB with utf-8, so should be fine. I put console.log and console.debug for console.log(tinymce.get('body').getContent() -- shows properly, so it goes like this into HTML Purifier. Hm! I didn't check for purifier makes with it :) wait a sec!

Comment: Okies so I checked, and TinyMCE is not doing nothing to it, same as HTML purifier. It's still proper. I just checked the database, it has: utf8_general_ci encoding, so looks fine. I think jQuery is missing something when appending html, like some utf-8 enforcement? Found something like decodeURIComponent, but no idea... When I refresh the website it all looks well, so jQuery has problem, not db, not html purifier, not website's html meta, etc... is jQuery somehow UTF-8 problematic?

Comment: I never had a problem with jQuery. I insist the problem is with the stripslashes, that's why I need the string before you use stripslashes in order to help you.

Comment: I guess I have found the guilty line: $new_thread_html = json_encode(array('status' => 1, 'success' => $new_thread)); -- before that line $new_thread is being returned properly and proper encoding. json_encode drops output to $new_thread_html with \u0142\u00f3. Any ideas then?

Comment: JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE helped, can you answer it to the main thread? :) I'd vote on you, you helped me a lot!

Comment: I was gonna tell you that, but I wanted to try it first ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP 5.4 You could use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag for `json_encode`.

In PHP 5.3 or lower here's a helper function:

```
function json_encode_unicode($input) {

    return preg_replace_callback(
        '/\\\\u([0-9a-zA-Z]{4})/',
        function ($matches) {
            return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*',$matches[1]),'UTF-8','UTF-16');
        },
        json_encode($input)
    );

}
```